# Views exposed filter between label AND replace with -

Tags: views

how do I change exposed filter BETWEEN label? There is default "AND"-text and I need to change it to  "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) to edit the form programmatically. This will go in a custom module.

Here's some boilerplate code:

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id !== 'views_exposed_form') {
    return;
  }

  if ($form_state['view']->name !== '<your_view_name>') {
    return;
  }

  $form['field_<your_field_name>']['max']['#title'] = '-';
}
```

Replace the view and field names with your particular ones. Hope it works for you.